# Changing focus to next input element in Selenium 2 with intern

Tags: selenium-webdriver, intern

I am trying to fill a login form like below, but doen't work

```
this.remote.get('http://localhost:8000/login')
  .keys('name1') // type on focused username input field
  .keys('\uE004') // press Tab (this doesn't change the focus??)
  .keys('pass') // type password
  .keys('\uE007'); // press Enter to submit
```

I need to emulate the actual user's actions here.

Comment: How did you verify that sending \ue004 did not change the focus?

Comment: Did you tried with `.keys('\t')`?

Comment: @C Snover, I am running test cases using intern's runner.js, on the new chrome window when running test cases, i can able to see that both user name and password are entered on first input element. BTW Enter works for me (it submits the form).

Comment: The problem is with `chrome 27`. Its working on `chrome 29`. But its also not working on other browsers (`Firefox (21)`, `Safari`) in Mac.

Answer (score -1):

Do you even try with the `Keys.TAB` constant ? like :

```
this.remote.get('http://localhost:8000/login')
  .keys('name1') // type on focused username input field
  .keys(Keys.TAB) // press Tab (this doesn't change the focus??)
  .keys('pass') // type password
  .keys(Keys.ENTER); // press Enter to submit
```

Comment: `ReferenceError: Keys is not defined`

Comment: @ManoHaran What language do you use ?

Comment: Global objects are not generated by Intern. `Keys` is not a thing.